# Using 'package as a filename in a declare-function statement?

Tags: package, declare

I just saw this line near the top of the file `use-package.el`:

```
(declare-function package-installed-p 'package)
```

How can `'package` be a useful 2nd argument, when the doc for `declare-function` says that the third argument should be a filename?

Comment: Good catch. I'd say that the doc string needs to be fixed, to more precisely state what the `FILE` argument is. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The doc string even says that that argument is looked up by `locate-library`, whose doc also says it must be a string. On the other hand, `declare-function` is for the byte-compiler, and the doc says that `FILE` is not used during byte-compilation. It could be clearer, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Could you please take a guess at what the code author was trying to achieve by providing `'package` as a second argument? Is that even legal, or functional? Should I learn to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can `'package` be a useful 2nd argument, when the doc for `declare-function` says that the third argument should be a filename?

It's a mistake in use-package.el, now [fixed](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/pull/342/commits/b4a17a59bf77c01f5fbc5a8c89fe67bb2128e82b).  If you run `check-declare` on the unfixed version you'll see in `*Messages*`:

```
Malformed declaration for `package-installed-p'
Malformed declaration for `(, command)'
```

The first is the `'package` mistake, the second is a false positive on `use-package` code that generates a `declare-function` statement call.

The reason it's like this, is that `check-declare-scan` works by regexp rather than actually parse the lisp code, so it can't be 100% certain about which statements are real.

Answer (score 0):

It means the function is defined by the file providing the feature `package` which is `package.el`. It's the same as with`(require 'foo)` which will also load a file `foo.el`from the`load-path`.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but it doesn't actually work. If you run `check-declare-file` on `use-package.el` and look at `*Messages*` you'll see ``Result: "Malformed declaration for `package-installed-p'"``.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed JohnWiegley, and he said the following:

That code was contributed by another, but I'm fairly certain it's just using the symbol-name of the symbol. The same sort of thing works with
eval-after-load:

```
(eval-after-load "foo" ...)
(eval-after-load 'foo ...)
```